# ASP.net unable to access database outside domain

Tags: database, dns, asp.net-2.0, iis-5

I have built a website using ASP.net 2.0, IIS 5.1 and SQL server 2000.

Accessing the website from the localhost and the same domain as the server is working correctly.

While accessing the website from an outside domain, will allow me to only access the ASP.net code, whenever there is a database access an error is generated.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Error:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 3/30/2011 4:54:28 PM 
Event time (UTC): 3/30/2011 1:54:28 PM 
Event ID: 44111a894d594247ad5e92e934d56c01 
Event sequence: 6 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/Root/SurveySite-12-129459668610468750 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /SurveySite 
    Application Path: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Survey\ 
    Machine name: MIND****** 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 560 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: SocketException 
    Exception message: No such host is known 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://10.7.1.20/surveysite/Default.aspx 
    Request path: /surveysite/Default.aspx 
    User host address: 10.1.1.65 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 12 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address, Boolean includeIPv6, Boolean throwOnFailure)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at _Default.btnStart_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\SurveySite\Default.aspx.cs:line 21
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Regards,

Comment: I tried adding NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE user to the database server and the database but it was of no use

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is not related to SQL server, I was calling the DNS server to request the machine name of an outside IP.

This produced an error.

All I had to do is remove that and store the IP address only.

I wonder if the host name of the client PC can be accessed through ASP.net .